# Send email using asp.net shows this error:The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I try to send email using this code:

```
  public void Semail(string subject, string messageBody, string toAddress)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(toAddress);
            //mail.To.Add("amit_jain_online@yahoo.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("noreplykaramaoozi@eesharif.edu");
            mail.Subject = subject;
            string Body = messageBody;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "sina.sharif.ir"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                ("noreplykaramaoozi@eesharif.edu", "*******");
            //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

But after executing i got this error:

```
 The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication required
```

Stack Trace :

```
[SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication required]
   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) +2162008
   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from) +287
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) +137
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +2188821
   Novitiate.fa.Register.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2948
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707
```

Best regards

Comment: Maybe `smtp.EnableSsl=true;`?

Comment: I change it to true but i got this error :The server can't support secure connection!!!

Comment: And that server is has an open port on 587? And you are not behind a proxy that needs authentication as well? Is a simple mailcient (outlook or thunderbird) capable of connecting?

Comment: You know we are a company that design a system for a university ,and we ask them that give us the information about their mail server and this gave us just a username and password and smtp server and a port ,i don't know any thing else about that!!!

Comment: Try `smtp.EnableSsl=false;` and `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials=false;`

Comment: @sallushan i tried both of these .same error!!!

Comment: I tried your SMTP on port 587 using `telnet`, it is working and responding, which means SMTP server is OK. Probably your credentials are NOT valid. You can try with `telnet`, see this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: Yes thank you @sallushan,what you mean that my  credentials are NOT valid?

Comment: Credentials NOT correct = User ID and/or Password are NOT correct

Comment: I sign in using my id and password!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51930/discussion-between-sallushan-and-e-a)

Answer (score 2):

Your gmail security preventing the message to access the gmail account. So,if you want to send the message you have to "turn off" the access for less secure app. When you do this you can easily send the message but, by risking your gmail security. So, it is upto you this definitely work.

link for changing security is given below

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if this helps:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress(Username);
mail.To.Add(TxtEmail.Text);
mail.Subject = Subject;
mail.Body = Body;
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Timeout = 20000;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: what is the different ?

Comment: Difference is in SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;  it provides you a Secure Connection and you are getting the error for it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider @Krunal Patil's answer there after login to your email account and act on the sent verification mail to grant access to your C# Application.